# Where does machine learning algorithme store the result?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, tensorflow

I think this is kind of "blasphemy" for someone who comes from the AI world, but since I come from the world where we program and get a result, and there is the concept of storing something un memory, here is my question :

Machine learning works by iterations, the more there are iterations, the best our algorithm becomes, but after those iterations, there is a result stored somewhere ? because if I think as a programmer, if I re-run the program, I must store previous results somewhere, or they will be overwritten ? or I need to use an array for example to store my results.

For example, if I train my image recognition algorithme with a bunch of cats pictures data sets, what are the variables I need to add to my algorithme, so if I use it with an image library, it will always success everytime I find a cat, but I will use what? since there is nothing saved for my next step ?

All videos and tutorials I have seen, they only draw a graph as decision making visualy, and not applying something to use it in future program ?

For example, this example, kNN is used to teach how to detect a written digit, but where is the explicit value to use ?

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/nearest_neighbor.py

NB: people clicking on `close request` or `downvoting` at least give a reason.

Comment: In simple nets at least, the "learning" is stored as specific edge weights. If you want to save the net, really just the layout and weights are important. And the activation function you used for each node of that varies too.

Comment: why tutorials found for beginner dont do this step ? they draw everything using `matplotlib` for example, and they talk about `accuracy` but nothing next!

Comment: Probably because how the net can be stored is irrelevant to how it works. And once you understand how they work, it's obvious how you would store one.

Comment: check out [Siraj Raval's Machine Learning Videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWN3xxRkmTPmbKwht9FuE5A) he explains all this stuff really well. I recommend his Introduction to Deep Learning videos and the Math of Intelligence videos.

Comment: so the whole work, is to detect the right `b` in `y=f(x)+b ` which is the error gap, and then finalize the algorithme for production ?

Comment: @Abdelouahab Yes. Again, in *simple FF nets*, the entirety of their "knowledge" is stored as the weights. The weights, in conjunction with the activation function produce the "intelligent" output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the more there are iterations, the best our algorithm becomes, but after those iterations, there is a result stored somewhere

What you're alluding to here is the *optimization* part.

However to optimize a model, we first have to *represent* it.

For example, if I'm creating a very simple linear model to predict house prices using its surface in square meters I might go for this model:

```
price = a * surface + b
```

That's the representation.

Now that you have represented the model, you want to optimize it, i.e. find the params `a` and `b` that minimize the prediction error.

> there is a result stored somewhere ?

In the above, we say that we have *learned* the params or weights `a` and `b`.

That's what you keep, the weights which come from optimization (also called training) and of course the model itself.

Comment: this is what confused me, because even on "practice" tutorials, they say "wait for the system to learn" and then "start using it" but without "programming" those values explicitly at the end !

Comment: @Abdelouahab Hey there glad my answer has helped you. I'd start with a simple perceptron or linear regression, as those have easy to grasp representation and optimization. Doing those will help understand what's being "saved" as you put it. Otherwise k-NN is a non-parametric model, it doesn't "save" anything, it is an instance-based model, meaning that it keeps the training examples to be used later for prediction.

Comment: so how about this example, there is no output to store ? https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

Comment: @Abdelouahab Perceptrons have parameters, see here https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py#L47

Comment: so with a good accuracy for example here, we keep the 256 value, and validate our model ?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some confusion. Let's clear it up.

Machine Learning models usually have parameters, and these parameters are trainable. This means a training algorithm find the "right" values of these parameters in order to properly work for a given task.
This is the learning part. The actual parameter values are "inferred" from training data.

What you would call the result of the training process is a model. The model is represented by formulas with parameters, and these parameters must be stored. Typically when you use a ML/DL framework (like scikit-learn or Keras), the parameters are stored alongside some information about the type of model, so it can be reconstructed at runtime.

Comment: so the framework that do it ? but here in this example, there is nothing saved explicitly, sorry for this question, but this confuses me, as it is not python which is used !
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/nearest_neighbor.py

Comment: @Abdelouahab My answer is generic, but in this case the KNN classifier doesn't have trainable parameters, it is not trained. You only need to store the training set in order to reconstruct the classifier. Also please note that Machine Learning is a large field and minimum working knowledge is required to use it. Even if you are a programmer.

Comment: What confuses me, is that tutorials telling that it is easy to start with, dont fix what should someone who "wants to program" what he needs

Comment: @Abdelouahab Most tutorials actually assume you have the minimum knowledge. I believe you don't have the minimum ML knowledge to use ML. You will nott learn ML by just programming tutorials.